# Cross compile clang for Android arm

Tags: android, android-ndk, clang, cross-compiling, llvm-clang

I am trying to cross-compile llvm/clang for Android arm.

I export the CC/CXX variables to the arm-linux-androideabi cross compilers, and then from my build folder I execute:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" --target arm-linux-androideabi --sysroot=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/ ../llvm
```

The build folder is in the same directory with the llvm source code.

I get the error:

```
rm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-m32'
```

I know, it has something to do with g++ `multilib` for `arm-linux` but I cannot find it in the NDK.

I have also tried all the steps that are listed [here](http://llvm.org/docs/HowToCrossCompileLLVM.html), and the guide found [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html), with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:
NOw I am using the following command:

> cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" --prefix=../outarm --target
>   arm-linux-androideabi --sysroot=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/
>   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  -DLLVM_ENABLE_PIC=False -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING=True -DLLVM_TABLEGEN=../osxbuild/bin/llvm-tblgen -DCLANG_TABLEGEN=../osxbuild/bin/clang-tblgen -DLLVM_TARGET_ARCH=ARM -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=ARM ../llvm

The compilation now begins, but it stops at 14% with the error:

> arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option
>   '-bundle'

EDIT2:
I removed all the relative paths to absolute ones.
And changed the compiler from gcc to clang. Clang recognises `-bundle`, but it does not use it. The full command w/ the error now is:
Command:

> cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"
>   -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/Desktop/clang-compilation/outarm -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE=arm-linux-androideabi --sysroot=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/  -DLLVM_ENABLE_PIC=False -DLLVM_TARGET_ARCH=ARM -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=ARM -DLLVM_TABLEGEN=$HOME/Desktop/clang-compilation/osxbuild/bin/llvm-tblgen
>   -DCLANG_TABLEGEN=$HOME/Desktop/clang-compilation/osxbuild/bin/clang-tblgen
>   -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-I$HOME/android/toolchains/gcc/include/c++/4.9/arm-linux-androideabi -I$HOME/android/toolchains/gcc/include/' $HOME/Desktop/clang-compilation/llvm
>
> make -j12

Error message:
    clang36++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-bundle'
    /Users/paschalis/android/toolchains/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: fatal error: -f/--auxiliary may not be used without -shared

Comment: After a couple of days fighting w/ cross-compilation flags and dependencies, I managed to get a working compiler.
I slightly modified this [work](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages),  and built clang, gcc, and all of their dependencies!

Comment: Can you please point to the script/patches to build clang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to build clang for android is:

- download AOSP [as described here](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)
- setup build commands from AOSP root (`source build/envsetup.sh`)
- cd to platform/external/llvm ([see more info here](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/q/project:platform/external/llvm))
- run `mm`  command to build
- cd to `AOSP root/platform/ndk`
- run `build/tools/build-llvm.py` ([see here](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/158740/))
- finally package will be in `AOSP/out` folder

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The problems are mainly caused because some libraries are either missing or stripped down on Android.
I `envsetup`  and then runned `make clang`.

Comment: @Paschalis do you have any success

Comment: no. aosp build failed. But thanks anyway! I haven't put much effort though, as I focused on the `termux-packages`. I 've build parts of aosp in the past, just not any external project (successfully) yet!

Comment: @Paschalis use exactly `mm` command instead of `make` in AOSP

Comment: Since I 've managed to compile it, I won't try to do it again using the aosp sources. But if you are sure that `mm` works, I 'll take your word and accept this answer!